# Can UUID & uuid_t data types be change after assignment?

Tags: c++, linux, winapi

Can a WinAPI `UUID` be changed after its been assigned? Can a Linux `uuid_t` be changed after its been assigned?

For example (example relating to `UUID` but the same question for `uuid_t`):

```
class Component
{
public:
    UUID id; // considering whether to make this public or not

    Component()
    { 
        UuidCreate(&id);
    }
};

Component c;
UuidCreate(c.id); // can it be changed after already being assigned? Is it constant?
```

Comment: Since you haven't declared either `c` or `Component::id` as `const` they can be easily changed.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). Why do you need to know, whether a variable of a particular type can be modified after it was constructed?

Comment: Definitely an XY problem. You don't "change" UUID's. The only sensible modifying operation is assignment, which you'd need e.g. in `std::vector<UUID>` to support `.erase`

Comment: @RossRidge The purpose of the question; I dont want users of class Component to be able to change `UUID` at all (by subclassing or outside interaction). Now changing to `const UUID` throws a compile error when calling `UuidCreate()` (Cannot convert from const UUID* to UUID*) so this doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: Please see [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329). Access modifiers are explained in all introductory books.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both `UUID` and `uuid_t` are just structs containing a series of integers. If any consumer can get a reference to it that isn't `const`, it will be able to modify it.

If you don't want consumers to change your `UUID`, the best approach is to make it a `private` member and only expose it to the outside world via an accessor that returns a const reference:

```
class Component
{
public:
    Component()
    { 
        UuidCreate(&id);
    }

    const UUID& GetId() const
    { 
        return id;
    }

private:
    UUID id;
};
```

Comment: The caller of `GetId()` can simply cast the `const` away and then modify the UUID directly since a reference to it is being returned. To avoid that, better to return the UUID by value instead of by reference, if at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: C++ uses the philosophy of "protecting against Murphy, not Machiavelli". Your "solution" to return by value still doesn't protect against `reinterpret_cast<UUID*>(&theComponent)`.